# How can I open Excel just after creating it programmatically in .NET?

Tags: .net, excel

Hi I am creating the application which creates the excel file pro grammatically.

Now I want to open it just after saving it pro grammatically in my code.

How I can open the file. Please reply...

Regards,
Girish

Comment: You have tagged your question as `asp.net`. What do you want to accomplish? Create and save file on server and open it there or want to send it to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very confusing question. You can open a workbook by using the Workbooks.Open method of Excel, if you are using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Process.Start( pathToSavedExcelFile );
```

This will open Excel if its installed.

Comment: Dear question is tagged `asp.net`

Comment: It is done using Process.Start( pathToSavedExcelFile );
thanks.